# Galasoft Messenger Show Window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I want to open a window from my ViewModel.
How can I create and show it using Galasoft Messenger?

```
public partial class View {
    public View() {
        InitializeComponents();
        //Register Open message
    }

    //This is called when ViewModel sends a message
    public void OpenView() {
        new View().Show();
    }
}

public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel() {
        //Send message to open some view
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us *your* code first, then we'll work with that.

Comment: Ugh, imo Views should not be responsible for your application's navigation. Make a ViewModel for that and use DataTemplates to show Views.

Comment: But how would you create an instance of a view and show it?

Comment: @VladimirNani: When you define a DataTemplate for a type (a ViewModel), and WPF "sees" that type (e.g. in ItemsControl.ItemsSource), WPF will create a view to the DataTemplate.

Comment: @VladimirNani You don't. You create a ViewModel and tell WPF to show that, and WPF will look for a DataTemplate that is defined for that ViewModel. For example, you would create a HomeViewModel and set it as the DataContext to some control, and a DataTemplate which tells WPF to draw the HomeViewModel as a HomeView. Here a link with a very simple MVVM example: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

Comment: Yes i get this, but i need to Show or ShowDialog new window.

Comment: @VladimirNani Usually I have an ApplicationViewModel which looks after the overall state of the application, and that includes window management. Although usually I prefer to keep everything in one window and use ContentControls or popups to change content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation does not require an object to be passed from ViewModel to View; therefore, just registering of type object, passing null, BUT the **token** is key.

```
public partial class View {
    public View() {
        InitializeComponents();
        //Register Open message BEFORE ViewModel calls Messenger.Default.Send
        Messenger.Default.Register<object>(this, ViewModel.OpenViewToken, p => { OpenView(); });
    }

    //This is called when ViewModel sends a message
    public void OpenView() {
        new View().Show();
    }
}

public class ViewModel {
    public static readonly Guid OpenViewToken = Guid.NewGuid();
    public ViewModel() {
        Messenger.Default.Send<object>(null, OpenViewToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this code may have syntax errors and such, as I put it down by memory.

Comment: How Messenger.Default.Register<object>(this, ViewModel.OpenViewToken, p => { OpenView(); }); will be registered if we are doing it in constructor of view which should be opened??

Comment: Vladimir, if not there, then in App.cs.  I didn't know if the View was just any View or the exact View. (Just ensure you Register before Send.)